# How to count the number greater than and less than a given set of numbers in python

Tags: python

Python sequence to count the number of subjects with mark greater than and less than 50.  Score 50 and below is considered fail.

SAMPLE INPUT

No. of subjects:

5

Enter marks:

65

51

34

46

54

SAMPLE OUTPUT

Sub passed: 3

Sub failed: 2

MY PROGRAM:

```
x=int(input("No. of subjects: \n"))
print("Enter marks:")
for i in range(x):
 y=[int(input())]
 count=0
 h=0
for j in y:
 if j>50:
  count=count+1
 if j<50:
  h=h+1
 print("Sub passed: " + str(count))
 print("Sub failed: " + str(h))
```

The above program is not returning any value after getting the input.

Comment: Please fix indentation of your code

Comment: Whats the exact output?

Comment: Output I'm getting is: Sub passed: 1
Sub failed: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `count` and `h` outside of the loop:

```
x=int(input("No. of subjects: \n"))
print("Enter marks:")
count = 0
h = 0
for i in range(x):
    y=[int(input())]
    for j in y:
        if j>50:
            count=count+1
        if j<50:
            h=h+1
print("Sub passed: " + str(count))
print("Sub failed: " + str(h))
```

Comment: Its still the same

Comment: it works for me giving the result: sub passed:3, sub failed: 2.
Check your code and make sure the indentation is correct, like in my example.

Comment: @misirtej what is your input

Comment: Same as in your example: No.of subjects:5, marks: 65,51,34,46,54

Comment: Yes, I found this works as well. So @misirtej I think you might be doing something funny with either your list comprehension or your indentation. If you take a look at [this](https://onlinegdb.com/Bk3Xfr-MD) you can see that it runs as expected.

Comment: @EugeneAnufriev yeah the indentation was wrong now it works..thankyou!

Answer (score 4):

it can be a little bit neater:

```
x=int(input("No. of subjects: \n"))
print("Enter marks:")

y= [int(input()) for i in range(x)]
    
passed = len([y_p for y_p in y if y_p > 50])
not_passed = len([y_n for y_n in y if y_n< 50])

print(passed) #According to question would print: 3
print(not_passed) #According to question would print: 2
```

First of all, you create a list with all inputs with list comprehension. Then you make another list with the condition passed and not passed.

Comment: Don't forget the output `print(passed)` etc

Comment: Or maybe even `return passed, not_passed`.